# Add objects from within JSON array into JavaScript array with keys remapped

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following json returned from an ajax request

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "task": "eat pizza",
    "username": "all"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "task": "drink soda",
    "username": "all"
  }
]
```

I am trying to add specific pieces of data from the json to an existing js array.

```
this.$todoData2 = [
    {
        'id': '5',
        'text': 'Cheese',
        'done': false
    },
]
```

I need to add json key id and its matching value - example: "id": key,

I need to add json key task as text with its matching value - example: "text": key

I need to add a "done": "false" to set so a final result would look like:

```
this.$todoData2 = [
    { 
        "id": "1",
        "text": "eat pizza",
        'done': false
    }
    { 
        "id": "2",
        "text": "drink soda",
        'done': false
    }
    {
        'id': '5',
        'text': 'Cheese',
        'done': false
    },
]
```

I have no examples of what I have tried as I am not sure where to even begin with this. Keep in mind that json may contain a lot more results.

Comment: Assuming your concern about *'...lot more results'*, you might want to take a [benchmark](https://jsperf.com/uoiwreffwoiuxc) into consideration. I'd suggest to run tests several times for a credible result - unfortunately, jsperf doesn't store historical data these days.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over the 'updates' Array, while [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter) the key / value pairs you want to use

Create your object, then [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) it to the Array

```js
const $todoData2 = [
    {'id': '5', 'text': 'Cheese', 'done': false},
];

const update = [
  {"id": "1", "task": "eat pizza", "username": "all"},
  {"id": "2", "task": "drink soda", "username": "all"}
];

update.forEach(({id, task}) => {
  $todoData2.push({
    'id': id,
    'text': task,
    'done': false
  });
});

console.log($todoData2);
```

Comment: Are you familiar with [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)?

Comment: Yes, I am. The other answers have covered solutions involving it

Answer (score 2):

You can merge both arrays and then use `map`.

```js
let arr = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "task": "eat pizza",
    "username": "all"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "task": "drink soda",
    "username": "all"
  }
]

let todoData2 = [
    {
        'id': '5',
        'text': 'Cheese',
        'done': false
    },
]

todoData2 = todoData2.concat(arr).map( obj => ({ id:obj.id, text:obj.task || obj.text , done:false  }) );
console.log(todoData2)
```

Comment: I'm glad I have inspired you to `concat()` instead of `push()` ;) though the latter would work just as perfect: with a bit of spread syntax `arr.push(...todoData2)`

Comment: I would be glad to be inspired, but honestly I was constantly improving my answer and if you saw the answer description it says 'merge', so the idea was there from the beginning, and this really is not the main concept of the answer.

Comment: ...let it be the coincidense, though our nice conversation *inspired* me to modify my own answer ;) thanks for a hint

Comment: Just to return the curtesy... Regarding *'...constantly improving my answer'*, it may have happened that the best is the enemy of the good - your approach may be not optimal from performance standpoint - while my answer and the one posted by @Light iterates through new items only, your code loops unnecessarily over existing items as well which [may cause](https://jsperf.com/uoiwreffwoiuxc) certain performance loss if there's already lot of them.

Comment: You have really inspired me now and have given me an assignment :).

Answer (score 1):

If the point here is to simply append and rename keys, it may by done as simple as that:

```js
const newItems = [{"id":"1","task":"eat pizza","username":"all"},{"id":"2","task":"drink soda","username":"all"}],
      existingItems = [{"id":"5","text":"Cheese","done":false}]
      
existingItems.push(...newItems.map(({id,task:text}) => ({id,text,done:false})))
      
console.log(existingItems)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%}
```